# How to remove or add class in nav when the browser window goes down or up

Tags: javascript

I have nav with four elements. I try add class (eg. with underline in css) in this element witch user is on. But when user scroll up or down I want remove that class and add in diffrent element in nav depending on where the user stayed.
Here is my code:

```
    let currentPosition = window.scrollY;
    let basicFunctionPosition = document.querySelector("#basic-function").offsetTop;
    let moreFunctionsPosition = document.querySelector("#more-functions").offsetTop;
    let signUpPosition = document.querySelector("#sign-up").offsetTop;
    let teamPosition = document.querySelector('#team').offsetTop;
    let dataSectionInNav = "";
    let dataSectionInNavTeam = "";

    if (currentPosition > basicFunctionPosition && currentPosition < moreFunctionsPosition) {
        dataSectionInNav = document.querySelector(".data-section-basic-func");
        dataSectionInNav.classList.add("sectionPositionInNav");

    } else if (currentPosition > moreFunctionsPosition && currentPosition < signUpPosition) {
        dataSectionInNav = document.querySelector(".data-section-more-func");
        dataSectionInNav.classList.add("sectionPositionInNav");

    } else if (currentPosition > signUpPosition && currentPosition < teamPosition) {
        dataSectionInNav = document.querySelector(".data-section-sign-up");
        dataSectionInNav.classList.add("sectionPositionInNav");
        dataSectionInNavTeam = document.querySelector(".data-section-team");
        dataSectionInNavTeam.classList.add("sectionPositionInNav");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over your conditionals when the user scrolls:

```
// Reference: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/

let last_known_scroll_position = 0;
let ticking = false;

function doSomething(scroll_pos) {
  // Do something with the scroll position
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY;

  if (!ticking) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      doSomething(last_known_scroll_position);
      ticking = false;
    });

    ticking = true;
  }
});
```

The example above uses requestAnimationFrame to ease the rate at which your function runs.

Check the [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Afterwards I use this code,

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    let currentPosition = window.scrollY;
    let basicFunctionPosition = document.querySelector("#basic-function").offsetTop;
    let moreFunctionsPosition = document.querySelector("#more-functions").offsetTop;
    let signUpPosition = document.querySelector("#sign-up").offsetTop;
    let teamPosition = document.querySelector("#team").offsetTop;
    let addClass = "";
    let delateClass = "";

    if (currentPosition < basicFunctionPosition) {
        delateClass = document.querySelectorAll(".data-section-basic-func, .data-section-more-func, .data-section-sign-up, .data-section-team");
        delateClass.forEach((item) => {
            item.classList.remove("highlightNav");
        });
    } else if (currentPosition > basicFunctionPosition && currentPosition < moreFunctionsPosition) {
        delateClass = document.querySelectorAll(".data-section-more-func, .data-section-sign-up, .data-section-team");
        delateClass.forEach((item) => {
            item.classList.remove("highlightNav");
        });
        addClass = document.querySelector(".data-section-basic-func");
        addClass.classList.add("highlightNav");

    } else if (currentPosition > moreFunctionsPosition && currentPosition < signUpPosition) {
        delateClass = document.querySelectorAll(".data-section-basic-func, .data-section-sign-up, .data-section-team");
        delateClass.forEach((item) => {
            item.classList.remove("highlightNav");
        });
        addClass = document.querySelector(".data-section-more-func");
        addClass.classList.add("highlightNav");
    } else if (currentPosition > signUpPosition && currentPosition < teamPosition) {
        delateClass = document.querySelectorAll(".data-section-basic-func, .data-section-more-func, .data-section-team");
        delateClass.forEach((item) => {
            item.classList.remove("highlightNav");
        });
        addClass = document.querySelector(".data-section-sign-up");
        addClass.classList.add("highlightNav");

    } else if (currentPosition > teamPosition) {
        delateClass = document.querySelectorAll(".data-section-basic-func, .data-section-more-func, .data-section-sign-up");
        delateClass.forEach((item) => {
            item.classList.remove("highlightNav");
        });
        addClass = document.querySelector(".data-section-team");
        addClass.classList.add("highlightNav");
    }
});


Can you write the code more simply?
```